# Relationship between context swich overhead and synchronization overhead?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, nonblocking, context-switch

I want to understand a simple scenario where there are so many threads competing for a synchronized shared resource. only one thread definitely will acquire a lock on the resource and all other must wait, now on resource availability each waiting thread will again attempt to acquire a lock and if failed then again suspended for next try. Is this scenario not increasing context switch overhead because threads are suspending and resuming again and again to grab the resource. I just want to ask that is there a directly proportional relationship between 1) synchronization overhead and context switch overhead 2) Introducing more shared variables by locks in any algorithm would increase context switch overhead i.e. There is a directly proportional relationship between number of shared resources and context switch overhead

---

Am I right?

---

Now my second question is "if non-blocking algorithms are used for synchronization in the above scenario i.e. if Atomic variable is used as a shared resource then what is the effect of context switch overhead in case of Atomic shared resource" . Will the competing thread for the shared resource will not suspend or resume i.e. how this phenomena of non-blocking synchronization is handled?

Comment: This seems like homework.

Comment: It is not a home work. I just want to clear my concept. Plz reply only if u can answer

Comment: I don't know how `synchronized` actually works in a JVM, but I'm _guessing_ that whenever there's more than one CPU, it is a hybrid implementation in which the loser of a race to lock a mutex will _spin_ for a short while, and only yield() (i.e., give up its time slice) if the owner of the mutex holds it for too long.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock)

Comment: Use the concurrent utilities, which avoid the notify-all problem.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting threads do not cause permanent context switches, see this question: [context switching thread waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598041/context-switching-thread-waiting)

(EDIT: some context switching can occur: for a short time the JVM tries to [spinlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock), but after a while the thread is suspended on the OS level, and if this happens before its quantum has expired, then this is an extra context switch)

All related state variables should be updated in a single atomic operation (for example in a single synchronized block), therefore the context switches caused by synchronization should not be proportional to the number of variables.

Atomic variables try to use [special CPU instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) in order to achieve atomicity, so there should be no context switch here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no wait() or notify() methods being used. It seems that these are not in the mix in your question. Please correct if this is not the case.

In this case, there would be context switches since all these Threads will be in RUNNABLE state and would be scheduled to run and there would be context switches. You could use the wait-notify approach to reduce this.

If you have more locking then there would be more overhead - that is correct.

If you use Atomic variables then that would utilize the compareAndSet approach wherein they would attempt to spin to provide, for example an atomic increment, in the processor slice allocated to it (See for Linux: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler). If it is not able to do the atomic increment in that then there would be no context switch else it would have to be revisited when this thread is switched back again.

Hope this helps.